# SQL Server query to filter data by different values in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:
[image]

Query 1 works fine and returns both records

```
select * 
from dbo.PersonalAttribute
where ProductId = '12345'
```

Query 2-3-4-5 works fine and filters on AttributeType and corresponding AttributeDescription.

```
select * 
from dbo.PersonalAttribute
where ProductId = '12345'
and (AttributeType = 'test1' and AttributeDescription = 0) -- will return one row


select * 
from dbo.PersonalAttribute
where ProductId = '12345'
and (AttributeType = 'test1' and AttributeDescription = 1) -- will return zero rows

select * 
from dbo.PersonalAttribute
where ProductId = '12345'
and (AttributeType = 'test2' and AttributeDescription = 1) -- will return one row

select * 
from dbo.PersonalAttribute
where ProductId = '12345'
and (AttributeType = 'test1' and AttributeDescription = 0) -- will return zero rows
```

Query 6 not working and returns 0 rows even all conditions are true:

```
select *
from dbo.PersonalAttribute
where ProductId = '12345'
and (AttributeType = 'test1' and AttributeDescription = 0) 
and (AttributeType = 'test2' and AttributeDescription = 1)
```

How can I rewrite Query 6 to have an ability to filter data by combination of vales in Attricute Type and Attribute Description columns, basically I need to select only when both conditions are true and if both conditions are not true no rows should be returned.

Thank you!

Comment: A column within a single row can't have two values at the same time.

Comment: what's the expected result of Query 6?

Answer (score 1):

The "and" means you are looking at the same row for two different things. You are allowed to pick up one fruit. You cannot pick up an apple and a pear. But you can pick up an apple or a pear. Change that "and" to "or" and wrap it in parenthesis:

```
select *
from dbo.PersonalAttribute
where ProductId = '12345'
and ((AttributeType = 'test1' and AttributeDescription = 0) 
 or (AttributeType = 'test2' and AttributeDescription = 1))
```

Comment: I need ability to filter on both AttributeTypes so or won't work for me.

Comment: @user285682 What do you mean? This query correctly returns both rows. So the query is ProductID = 12345 and (condition 1 or condition 2). Condition 1 is (type = test1 and description = 0) while Condition 2 is (type = test2 and description = 1).

Answer (score 0):

One option is via a JOIN.   You can create a Temp table or even a Table Variable to hold the desired combinations

```
select P.* 
 From  dbo.PersonalAttribute P
 Join ( values  ('test1',0)
               ,('test2',1)
      ) V(AttrT,AttrD)
  on  AttributeType        = AttrT
  and AttributeDescription = AttrD
  and  ProductId = '12345'
```

Comment: this won't do the same as original non working query, that query should select only when both conditions are satisfy if not should not return any rows. Thank you!

Comment: @user285682  Are you sure ?   Both criteria would have to be be met.

Comment: yes I am sure :)

Comment: Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/2cY2pswC   Perhaps I'm not understanding your desired results, but the JOIN will apply a multi-column filter

Comment: I have changed your example a bit: 
Insert Into PersonalAttribute Values 
 (1,12345,'test1',0),(2,12345,'test2',1),(3,12346,'test2',0)
Two rows returned.
select P.* From  PersonalAttribute P
 Join ( values  ('test1',0),('test2',1)) V(AttrT,AttrD)
  on  AttributeType = AttrT
  and AttributeDescription = AttrD
  and  ProductId = '12345'  
One row returned and I need in this case no rows to be returned.
select P.* From  PersonalAttribute P
 Join ( values  ('test1',0),('test2',0)) V(AttrT,AttrD)
  on  AttributeType = AttrT
  and AttributeDescription = AttrD
  and  ProductId = '12345'

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Lq-FM8Yy first query returns two rows as both criteria's are true, second query returns one raw since only one criteria is true but in this case I need no rows to be returned.